# Read SMS in other language except English

Tags: java, android, localization

My application sends and receives message in English.But I want a functionality by which, whenever a new message is received,it would be in English,but when user reads message it should be readable in Hindi language.

Is there any solution for that??

Comment: nice to sound. Let see..

Comment: Are you talking about to translate the message from English to Hindi..?

Comment: Yes..when message arrive in inbox..it would be in english. but when user read that sms from my application it should be readable in HINDI or any other language which i want...is there any solution???

Comment: If thats all, then simply translate the message. You can use Google Translate APIs for that.

Comment: i said ..i want to read SMS in Hindi ...caan u hwlp me in this?

Comment: thanks a lot all of u ..for guiding me..god bless all of u.

Answer (score 2):

Use the google api

[Google Java Translation](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/)

Comment: **FYI**: Before building a whopper of an app on the translate API you should consider that it's been deprecated and scheduled to disappear around [Dec 2011](http://www.webcitation.org/5z1B8xoUj)